# Flexdashboard cannot read dataframe?

Tags: r, flexdashboard

this is the only code so far in my flexdashboard rmd file.

```
renderValueBox(valueBox(value = unique(FB_basic$Fans), caption = "Fans"))
```

however i get this error

> Warning: Error in unique: object 'FB_basic' not found

even though FB_basic is in my projects environmental variable. Help please!!

Comment: Most likely issue: When you knit a `flexdashboard` then as any Rmarkdown file it is rendered in a fresh R session without access to any variables in your global environment, i.e. you have to import your data in your Rmd file.

Comment: @stefan ok that would make sense. But how would I import the dataframe from my projects environment into the Rmd file?

Answer (score 1):

An easier way to build a **Flex dashboard** is to create a new R Markdown project in R Studio, then go to **From Template** and select **Flex Dashboard**. That way, you will be presented with an R code editor where you can easily import data frames and files from your project's environment and render them in your dashboard as shown in the image below.

You can even switch to the visual editor if that is what you prefer.

[image]

I hope this helps!